Calculate observed and baseline probability in distributed setup
I am following this Instagram algo to find trending hashtags.
https://instagram-engineering.com/trending-on-instagram-b749450e6d93
I am confused here how this observed and baseline probability is calculated from counter?

For each hashtag and place, we store counters of how many pieces of media were shared using the hashtag or place in a 5-minute window over the past 7 days. For simplicity, let us focus on hashtags for now, and let’s assume that C(h, t) is the counter for hashtag h at timet (i.e., it is the number of posts that were tagged with this hashtag since time t-5min till timet). Since this count varies a lot between different hashtags and over time, we normalize it and compute the probability P(h, t) of observing the hashtag h at time t.

Is it freq of a hashtag in current window divided by sum of this hashtag of all times
Or,
freq of the hashtag divided by total count of all hashtags in current time window of 5min?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How they are calculating the observed probability and baseline probability? How are they normalizing the counter value?
